# Arrays to Json format

Tags: mysql, json, laravel-5.6, php7.2

PHP 7.2.8

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB

Laravel Framework 5.6.29

Таблицы следующие:

```
CREATE TABLE `companys` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `company_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB


CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `company_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_clients_1_idx` (`company_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_clients_1` FOREIGN KEY (`company_id`) REFERENCES `companys` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB


CREATE TABLE `clients_values` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_clients_values_1_idx` (`client_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_clients_values_1` FOREIGN KEY (`client_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Необходимо привести к такому JSON'у:

```
company_id: 1,
clients: [
{
  client_id: '1',
  client_name: 'Иванов И.И.',
  client_values: [
    {
      value_id: 1,
      value: '555'
    },
    {
      value_id: 2,
      value: '333'
    },
  ],
},
{
  client_id: '2',
  client_name: 'Сидоров С.С.',
  client_values: [
    {
      value_id: 4,
      value: '888'
    },
    {
      value_id: 5,
      value: '999'
    },
  ],
},
]
```

Пробую примерно так:

```
    $companys = DB::select('SELECT * FROM companys WHERE id=1;');
    $clients = DB::select('SELECT * FROM clients WHERE company_id=1');
    $clients_values = DB::select('SELECT * FROM clients_values;');

        $data = [
            'id' => $companys[0]->id,
            'type' => $companys[0]->name,
            'clients' => [],
        ];

        foreach ($funnel_steps as $key => $value) {
            $data['clients'][$key] = [
                'id' => $clients[$key]->id,
                'name' => $clients[$key]->name,
                'clients_values' => [],
            ];
        }

        foreach ($clients_values as $key => $value) {
            $data['clients']['clients_values'][$key] = [
                'id' => $clients_values[$key]->id,
                'name' => $clients_values[$key]->value,
            ];
        }
```

companys и client встают куда нужно, но не могу поставить clients_values, на свое место, как сопоставить id из clients, и client_id из clients_values?

Можно ли оптимизировать, и сделать такой JSON из одного запроса?

```
SELECT * FROM clients_values
INNER JOIN clients ON clients.id=clients_values.client_id
INNER JOIN companys ON companys.id=clients.company_id
```

Comment: MySQL не умеет создавать многоуровневые JSON "влоб". Хотя всё равно, по-моему, проще собрать требуемый формат JSON-функциями, а то и  обычными строковыми функциями, с использованием подзапросов, чем устраивать возню на клиенте. Создайте fiddle и укажите точно версию MySQL.

Comment: "Влоб" конечно это не сделать, хотелось бы минимизировать кол-во mysql запросов. Я думаю, именно это будет узкое место, если json будет достаточно большой.

Comment: *хотелось бы минимизировать кол-во mysql запросов.* Один - устроит?

Comment: Один было бы идеально)

Answer (score 0):

Задачу решил дополнительной функцией:

```
foreach ($funnel_steps as $key => $value) {
    $data['clients'][$key] = [
        'id' => $clients[$key]->id,
        'name' => $clients[$key]->name,
        'clients_values' => $this->clientValuesToArray($clients[$key]->id),
    ];
}
```

Надеялся, что есть более оптимальное решение. Какая-нибудь хитрая функция, которая может преобразовать массив в многоуровневый json, понимая связи через Id.